# $p$-operator space structure on Banach algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, banach-algebras, operator-spaces

There is an abstract characterization of operator algebras, which says that if $A$ is an operator space that is also an approximately unital Banach algebra, then the following are equivalent:

1. For any $n\geq 1$, $M_n(A)$ is a Banach algebra.
2. $A$ is an operator algebra.

Is there any similar statement for Banach algebras that are also $p$-operator spaces? More specifically, for such Banach algebras, if (1) is satisfied, is there anything that can be said about the algebra being an $L^p$ operator algebra?

Comment: @YemonChoi I took that statement from (part of) Thm 2.3.2 in the book Operator Algebras and their Modules by Blecher and Le Merdy. I'm not sure whether I missed certain conventions or misunderstood something.

Comment: OK, I have looked at the theorem, and I retract my earlier comment -- I had forgotten how strong the assumption of submultiplicativity for the norm on M_n(A) is. It seems to me that if one wants an $L_p$ version then one has to work out an analogue of the Haagerup tensor product, since that is used ultimately to produce the desired realization of A as a closed subalgebra of B(H)

Comment: It looks like Theorem 3.3 in Le Merdy's article titled "Representation of a quotient of a subalgebra of B(X)" is the analog that I was asking about (when the algebra has a unit of norm one). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I have taken a quick look at Le Merdy's article and it does seem to do what you want, although note that $A$ is a priori assumed to be a closed subspace of B(X) for some $SQ_p$-space $X$. It is not clear from the wording of your question what assumptions you are putting on $A$, and therefore it is not entirely clear to me what the precise theorem you hope to prove is.

Comment: Yes, such spaces are the (concrete) $p$-operator spaces so they are the kind of spaces I was considering. On the other hand, I think Le Merdy's theorem does not include the case $p=1$.

Comment: The p=1 world will be so different (IMO) from the p=2 world that it should be excluded from considerations if you want to have a theory that parallels what is done for operator spaces. This is well known to people in the world of Banach algebras.